# Running Xamarin.UITest on Macos for iOS: DeviceAgent start session failed

Tags: c#, ios, macos, xamarin, mono

When running Xamarin.UI tests locally on Macos machine with simulator (iPhone X iOS 11.3) having next output:

Full log file: /var/folders/_4/g83h2w4975bfsv5t19_qwf5h0000gn/T/uitest/log-2018-04-17_14-29-22-619.txt

iOS test running Xamarin.UITest version: 2.2.4

Skipping IDE integration as important properties are configured. To force IDE integration, add .PreferIdeSettings() to ConfigureApp.

Skipping local screenshots. Can be enabled with EnableScreenshots() when configuring app.

Sim check: App not installed.

1 - LaunchTestAsync:
    deviceId: 9108E538-E44E-4D6D-9AA8-BB9A2CCCDDC1

1 - Launching simulator if not already running

7 - Launching simulator if not already running

7 - InstallApp:
    pathToBundle: /Users/{user}/Projects/UITest/iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone7.2-10.1/UITest.iOS.app
    deviceId: 9108E538-E44E-4D6D-9AA8-BB9A2CCCDDC1

8 - HTTP request failed, retry limit hit
Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:879 
  at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0016d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:187 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0003c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:904 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:550 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:535 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+d__64.MoveNext () [0x0029d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5533/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:392

Packages that are used:

- Xamarin.TestCloud.Agent
- 0.21.5 Xamarin.UITest
- 2.2.4 NUnit 2.6.3

Tested on clean new Xamarin.Forms project.
Already tried to remove xdb folder - didn't help.
Anybody has experience how to solve this?

Comment: `Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)` The error is fairly self-exploratory...

Comment: Not really. Since I saw similar issues from other people, but no stable solution yet

Comment: If the Mac that you are running the simulator on can not reach your server or is refused because you are not able to connect on a secure channel to that server, then you will get that error in your log... `ConnectFailure  / Connection refused at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect `.  Can you connect to that server via PostMan/curl/... from the same machine? If so, post the HttpWebRequest code along with the build options for the TLS/SSL implementation that you have chosen in the Xamarin.iOS project settings.

Comment: I am running tests on my Mac machine (so this is the same machine): VS and Emulator on the same machine

Comment: Did you solved this issue?